# Asp.net parameters showing as null when i know the value isnt blank

Tags: css, asp.net, excel, gridview

I'm getting the below error when passing through a value that i know is there.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'
```

I'm populating a grid view which has a single output. I'm then using that out put to populate the new grid view.

```
            OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection();
        string path1 = Server.MapPath("Price_List.xlsx");
        String connString1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;'";
        conn1.ConnectionString = connString1;
        conn1.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$] Where [Meter Type] =" + GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text, conn1);
        OleDbDataReader rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


        GridView2.DataSource = rd1;
        GridView2.DataBind();
```

I know the code

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text
```

shows the single out out of grid view 1 as i have tested this in a text box and displays what i what it to display.

I cannot see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You may need to use OleDbParameter too and attach it to OleDbCommand rather hard coding value in SQL command query

Comment: Can you point mt in the right direction, not over sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Meter Type] is a string field, you're missing your single quotes in the sql:

`OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$] Where [Meter Type] = '" + GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text + "'", conn1);`